# Gradle sync error in Android Studio for appcompact-v7:26.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio 3 in my system and assigned a API level 26 version 1 & 2 both (Android Oreo (8.0) to the project as shown in the image below:

[image: SDK Platform installed image]

And the SDK tools as 26.1.1 version installed as shown in image below:

[image: SDk tools]

Code in app module gradle:

[image: version reference in gradle]

Troubleshooting steps i have tried so far:

1. changing the versions of appcompact-v7 in gradle file to (26.0.0,26.0.1,26.0.2,26.1.1,26.1.2) and sync.
2. Invalidate cache and restart.
3. Rebuild project.

I did not get success in above methods. I get the error messages as:

[image: error message]

and in more details according to the respective versions I get error msg as:

[image: more error details]

But if I change the version as appcompact-v7:+ then it works fine and gradle sync is successful. I know that it is not a good practice to use the above method.

How can we resolve the above error. Or is there any way we can find out which version of appcompact the studio is downloading when we add reference as appcompact-v7:+ ?

I am new to Android Studio and Android development.

Comment: Did you add the Google repository ??

Comment: yes i have added google() and checked but still no success

Comment: You connect through a Proxy ??

Comment: yes. i have a corporate network and i have already successfully checked the connection in HTTP proxy as for time being i have got the complete network admin rights.

Comment: I think that you're pointing for the Entrprise own Repository (Nexus for example). Try to add the google() repo URL in your Nexus configuration repos.

Comment: no we dont have any such internal enterprise repository

Comment: The log shows 443 connection refused. It must be something wrong with your proxy or internet access

Comment: no dude..i didnt get the solution mentioned in above link working so i posted a new question

Answer (score 1):

Since API 26, Google has moved the repository to Google() repo. You must add it in your build.gradle project file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and don't forget to update your gradle wrapper. You can use this command:

```
>gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.2
```

Comment: Done with all of the above steps but no success yet.

Comment: i tried to check the HTTP Proxy connection. The test connection was successful and as i have said i have got the complete admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Check ur build files. This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip
```

also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 vesion as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sry it would be better as a comment, but I can't)

If you are behind a proxy check your gradle.properties with proxy configuration

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[url/ip]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[port]
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[url/ip]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[port]
```